# Scheduled Task start time and action

Tags: windows, cmd

I am trying to get into my application a list with the running scheduled tasks in Windows. The provided application(Task Scheduler) will not do, I need some sort of API or a way to get them from the command line.

I found out that this can be done with the [schtasks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_change) command. The problem is, that I cannot view the start time of the task, nor the current action in the running task.

How can I also get the current acion an the start time of a scheduled task in the Windows command line?

Comment: does `schtasks /query /v` help? (`/fo list` helps to get it more readable)

Comment: @Stephan Yes, it helps, but only for viewing the start time. Please post an answer with this. Also, do you happen to have any other idea on how to get the actions from a task? I have some tasks that execute more than one action, so I would like to see what the task currently does. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
schtasks /query /v /fo list
```

shows Information for all scheduled tasks.
Sadly I have no knowledge how to get Info about what actions are planned, if there are more than one. All I get is:

```
Auszuführende Aufgabe:                                       Mehrere Aktionen
```

(obviously I've got a german Windows) It means: "Tasks to do:  several actions"

Comment: Apparently there is another command - `wevtutil` which allows you to read event logs and the Task Scheduler does create some event logs. So an idea would be to see the started but not ended actions of the currently running tasks. Danke fuer deine Hilfe!